# Embedding ruby in c++, problem with ruby libraries

Tags: c++, ruby

I want to have a ruby interpreter in my c++ application. I found an article about it:
http://aeditor.rubyforge.org/ruby_cplusplus/index.html
But here they use a makefile to compile the program, and I'm not really familiar with this consequently I can't modify it properly.
I also found a really simple example here:
http://my.opera.com/subjam/blog/embedding-ruby-in-c-programs
But again I encounter a compilation problem.
They say you need to type 
g++ -o ruby_test1 ruby_test1.c -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i486-linux/ -lruby1.8
And this makes sense to me, but I don't have the "i486-linux" folder in my ruby directory. I installed it via apt-get and I chose the '-dev' version.

Where can I find the needed file?

PS
I'm using Ubuntu. If I like this interpreter I'll also want to make it work on Windows, so 
any help  will, be appreciated.

I'm not interested in some substitutes for ruby, like tinyrb or whatever.

Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have an i486 architecture. like for me it's "x86_64-linux" run the `arch` command to see what architecture you have and then put that infront of "-linux" and see if it that is there.