# Statically link ruby libraries to c++ application

Tags: c++, ruby

I recently asked a question concerning embedding ruby in a c++ application

[Embedding ruby in c++, problem with ruby libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074797/embedding-ruby-in-c-problem-with-ruby-libraries)

Now I encountered another problem related to this. I managed to compile and run this application, but i can't link ruby statically. This is what my console says:

```
####:~/Desktop/rubyParser$ g++ -o ruby_test ruby_test.c -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/ -static -lruby1.8
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lruby1.8
```

But if I open /usr/bin, there is a "ruby1.8" file (no extension). Probably i need another file..
I'm using Ubuntu and I'm NOT a Linux expert of course, so please be patient with me :)

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Bye

Answer (score 2):

By specifying `-lruby1.8` the linker will look for a file named `libruby1.8.so` in the standard library locations (probably `/usr/lib/` or `/usr/local/lib`).

Take a look at those directories to see if you have something like that in there.

If not, have you installed the *development* package of ruby ? If only the linking process fails, I would assume you have (otherwise, it is likely that you wouldn't have the headers as well).

I never linked with ruby, but have you tried specifying `-lruby` instead of `-lruby1.8` ?

Comment: 1) There is "libruby1.8.so" in /usr/lib

2) Development package is installed

3) -lruby doesn't work either

Comment: There are even more:

libruby1.8.so -> libruby1.8.so.1.8.7 ; 
libruby1.8.so.1.8 -> libruby1.8.so.1.8.7 ;
libruby1.8.so.1.8.7 ;
52 libruby1.8-static.a

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the binary to your PATH ?

Comment: If you mean this: "g++ -o ruby_test ruby_test.c -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/ -I/usr/bin/ -static -lruby1.8", it doesn't change anything.

Comment: what will be the rubypath?
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/, some file.rb here; /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux, some file.so file.h  here; or maybe something else?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to, if you've recently installed the Ruby libraries in question, go to the command-line and type in `sudo ldconfig` to refresh `ld`'s configuration files with the latest versions of your libraries and their locations.

Edit: From the comments below, you'll only need to-do this step if you run into a run-time linking problem, which you haven't at this point.  But it's at least something to keep in-mind as it has solved run-time linking problems for me in the past (i.e., helped me with GMP).

Comment: The OP is experiencing **linking** problems. `ldconfig` only creates the symbolic links needed at **runtime**. You're right that it could be an issue, but not at this stage.